# enum as string and number in the database

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

i have a table

```
table Foo
(
    id,
    FooType,
    FooTypeName,
)
```

FooType is an enum with fixed values hence i want to map it to

```
public virtual FooType FooType { get; set; }
```

How can i serialize the property in both columns but use only one to read and query?

Which mapping (xml, Mapping by Code, FluentMapping) doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create `FooTypeName` as a string property projecting the value of `FooType`, and map it as `readonly`.

---

Alternatively, if you don't *need* `FooTypeName` at all, just ignore it in your model and keep it updated with a trigger.

---

Or, if you feel like coding a lot, create a user type that maps `FooType` to the two columns.

Comment: wouldn't that polluting my domain class? I have a fairly awkward legacy database and i want to keep my domainmodel as clean as possible so if the apps still using the old schema run out i can use automapping to quickly generate a nice one. I do not want to carry over broken design.

Comment: Alright, there are two alternatives... I prefer the second option, just because it's easier.

Comment: hmm, i already have a lot IUsertypes and even implemented a base class. I think i go with this option. thx